# Convert string array of tuples to input and outputs

Tags: python

Have a string array in this format :

```
stringList = ['(0.0,[0.0,0.0,0.0])\n' , '(1.0,[1.0,0.0,0.0])\n']
```

How to convert to :

```
inputs = [0.0 , 1.0]
outputs = [ [0.0,0.0,0.0] , [1.0,0.0,0.0] ]
```

Closest I have is :

```
inputs = []
outputs = []

for l in stringList : 
    inputs.append(np.array(float(l.split(',')[0].replace('(' , ''))))

for l in stringList : 
     outputs.append(float(l.split(',')[1].replace('[' , '')))

print(inputs)
print(outputs)
```

Which prints :

```
[array(0.0), array(1.0)]
[0.0, 1.0]
```

How to convert to :

```
inputs = [0.0 , 1.0]
outputs = [ [0.0,0.0,0.0] , [1.0,0.0,0.0] ]
```

?

Comment: Why are you using a `numpy.array` if you know you want a list of floats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your strings are of tuple format. You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate it to a tuple, and then append the results to outputs correspondingly:

```
stringList = ['(0.0,[0.0,0.0,0.0])\n' , '(1.0,[1.0,0.0,0.0])\n']
inputs = []
outputs = []

from ast import literal_eval
for s in stringList:
    t = literal_eval(s)
    inputs.append(t[0])
    outputs.append(t[1])

inputs
# [0.0, 1.0]

outputs
# [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Or a shorter version, you can use `zip` after the `literal_eval`:

```
inputs, outputs = zip(*map(literal_eval, stringList))
```

Comment: No need to strip the strings. `literal_eval` doesn't care about newline.

Comment: @Ryan Right. Just realize that.

Comment: last one is very ninja-ic, +1

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not pythonic as the other answers, but here's my try:

**Code:**

```
stringList = ['(0.0,[0.0,0.0,0.0])\n' , '(1.0,[1.0,0.0,0.0])\n']

inp = []
outp = []

for i in stringList:    
    x = i.split(',[')[0].replace("(", "").replace("\n", "")
    y = i.split(',[')[1].replace("])", "").replace("\n", "").split(',')
    z = [float(i) for i in y]

    inp.append(float(x))
    outp.append(z)

print(inp)
print(outp)
```

**Output:**

```
[0.0, 1.0]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, using split and some character removal:

```
import re

inputs = []
outputs = []

for s in stringList:
    # delete (, ), [, ], \n characters from string
    tmp = re.sub('[\(\)\n\[\]]', '', s) 

    # first float to inputs, others to outputs
    tmp_i, *tmp_o = [float(i) for i in tmp.split(',')]

    inputs.append(tmp_i)
    outputs.append(tmp_o)
```

### EDIT

in case you're still using Python 2, change the assignment of `tmp_i` and `tmp_o`:

```
    tmp_list = [float(i) for i in tmp.split(',')]

    inputs.append(tmp_list[0])
    outputs.append(tmp_list[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this one

```
stringList = ['(0.0,[0.0,0.0,0.0])\n' , '(1.0,[1.0,0.0,0.0])\n']
inp_list = map(lambda x: eval(x)[0], stringList)
op_list = map(lambda x: eval(x)[1], stringList)
```

output:

```
print inp_list # [0.0, 1.0]
print op_list # [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```